# Can I use Arrays.fill with a 2d array? If so how do I do that?

Tags: java, arrays

Can you use `Arrays.fill` on 2d arrays? When I type it, it says there is an issue with `fill` Here is my code. `fill` is red when I type it into my compiler.

```
public void FillArray(String[][] SC){
        for (int i = 0; i < SC.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; i < SC[i].length; j++){
                Arrays.fill(SC[i][j], "-");
            }
        }
    }
```

If `Arrays.fill` won't work how else would I be able to fill a 2d array with `"-"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## No, it doesn't work.

However, all is not lost! You don't even need to have the nested loop. Just do this:

```
public void FillArray(String[][] SC){
    for (int i = 0; i < SC.length; i++){
        Arrays.fill(SC[i], "-");
    }
}
```

Using a loop is how you can fill each of the inner arrays separately, but [`Arrays.fill`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object)) handles the inner loop for you.

Comment: So that will fill every position with "-"?

Comment: Yes, it will fill every position.